# What a single & means in objc syntax?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In code I found some lines:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //1
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; //2
UIUserNotificationSettings *currentSettings = application.currentUserNotificationSettings; //3
BOOL badgeAllowed = currentSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge; //4
```

I know what mean lines 1 to 3, but what means line 4?

It returns `BOOL` but if I want both parts to be true there should be `&&` instead of `&`. Why there is only one `&`? What does it mean? I would like to read some about it, but I do not know what is it.

Comment: It's "C" operator, means binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` is a logical operator AND

`&` is a bitwise operator AND.

That means that every bit of the resulting number is set only if both operands have that bit set.

In this specific case

```
currentSettings.types
```

is a mask of allowed notification types (a bit is set for every type).
ANDing it with `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` results in

1. If `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` is part of the mask, only that specific bit is set in the result.
2. If `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` is not part of the mask, the result has all bits set to zero.

Then the integer is considered as a boolean, which means non-zero = true, zero = false.

The last step can be written explicitly (which is better IMHO)

```
BOOL badgeAllowed = ((currentSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the C bitwise AND operator.  It compares each bit of the left and right operands and set the corresponding result bit to 1 if the source bits are both 1 and 0 otherwise.  For your code, the bit mask `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` is used to check whether that individual bit is set in `currentSettings.types`.  In C all non-zero values are interpreted as true so if `currentSettings.types` has the `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` bit set `badgeAllowed` will be true, although not necessarily `1`.